# Sqflite flutter warning

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I am facing this warning using the sqflite package

```
*** sqflite warning ***

You are changing sqflite default factory.
Be aware of the potential side effects. Any library using sqflite
will have this factory as the default for all operations.

*** sqflite warning ***
```

How to remove these warnings

I have added

```
sqfliteFfiInit();
databaseFactoryOrNull = databaseFactoryFfi;
```

in my void main.

Comment: I recognized that today as well but I'm not aware of any changes. So I'm interested as well if this has any side-effects or needs attention. Using the verison: 2.2.8

Answer (score 0):

```
databaseFactoryOrNull = null;
sqfliteFfiInit();
```

I have used this in my void main. And the warning is no longer shown.